# Mime type checking inside AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function, which will be triggered when uploading a file to S3 bucket. I would like to check the type of the uploaded file inside the lambda function using the mime type check. I know that we can use contentType for this, but it will only check the file extension I guess and fail to identify the exact file type, if the uploaded file has wrong extension. Is there anyway to check the mime type of the uploaded file in lambda function? Please provide the sample code or any any reference, if there are any.

Thanks,

Comment: *"I know that we can use contentType for this, but it will only check the file extension I guess"* not the extension, it will check the `Content-Type` header sent with the upload, which is only as good as whatever set it.  You'd have to download the object inside the Lambda environment to actually check its MIME type.

Comment: Thanks Michale for the response.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Python there are 2 libraries, which can detect MimeType of the file:

- **mimetypes** can detect Mime Type by filename (by extension).
- **magic** can detect Mime Type by file content.

Sample Python code

```
import mimetypes # Included in AWS Lambda
import magic     # Not included in AWS Lambda, needs to be a part of Lambda package

fileName =    # File name, as a string
fileContent = # Content of the file, binary
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
contentType = mimetypes.guess_type(fileName)[0]
if contentType is None:
    contentType = mime.from_buffer(fileContent)
```

The code above will first try to detect mime type by extention, then, if fails, by file content.

Sample Lambda function, doing mine type detection: https://github.com/maxmode/static_website_autosync_terraform/blob/master/lambda/unzip.py#L31